# How to access regex back reference in Apache 2.4 if statement

Tags: regex, apache2.4, backreference

I am trying to process a certain request header injected and strip out a particular value and set a new request header with that value.

The existing header looks like this and I want to get to the actual clientip

`OSGD-Signed-Data="clientip=x.x.x.x;gateway-features=routing-token-nocert,gateway-http-upgrade;timestamp=1532711365214"`

So I created an <If> statement with a regex

`<If "%{http:OSGD-Signed-Data} =~ /clientip=([^;]*);/">
        RequestHeader set X-Client-IP $0
</If>`

which matches, but I can't figure out how to use the back reference to set my new header

Comment: Try `set X-Client-IP $1`

Comment: That creates an error ```Invalid command 'Set'```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't seem to be possible *directly*. The [Apache 2.4 documentation for expr](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#other) states:

> The strings $0 ... $9 allow to reference the capture groups from a
>   previously executed, successfully matching regular expressions. They
>   can normally only be used in the same expression as the matching
>   regex, but some modules allow special uses.

I solved this by using `SetEnvIf` within the `<If>`. Your config would look something like this:

```
<If "%{http:OSGD-Signed-Data} =~ /clientip=([^;]*);/">
    SetEnvIf OSGD-Signed-Data clientip=([^;]*); CLIENT_IP=$1
    RequestHeader set X-Client-IP %{CLIENT_IP}e
</If>
```

This has the drawback that the regex needs to be specified twice (and is therefore also evaluated twice) - once in the `<If>` expression and again in `SetEnvIf`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and solution. I can now use
```<RequireAny>
  Require expr "%{env:CLIENT_IP} =~ /156.151.8./"
</RequireAny>```

Comment: @Jamgold glad it helped. If you consider this as an answer your question, please consider marking it as such ;-)